# Deleting a Symbolic Link in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

If you delete a directory symbolic link in Windows 7, using explorer's right-mouse menu delete command, will you also delete the contents of the directory it points to?
If you do, is there any way of just killing the symbolic link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only delete the directory symbolic link (made by `mklink /d`) itself. I have tested:

- Deleting the symbolic link
- Multi-selecting and deleting the symbolic link and another file or folder
- Deleting a folder containing the symbolic link

In all cases, the link target is unaffected.

The same behavior apply to directory junctions as well.